# Unable to deploy a project to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

EDIT:
I am sorry: The title was wrong and misleading. I am starting Tomcat, but unable to deploy a project that has web services..

I downloaded a new TomCat (version 7.0.47) added following libs to {Tomcat}/libs:

- jaxb-impl.jar
- jaxws-api.jar
- jaxws-rt.jar gmbal-api-only.jar
- management-api.jar
- stax-ex.jar
- streambuffer.jar
- policy.jar
- ha-api.jar

and getting this error:

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.<init>(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.doCreate(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TubelineAssemblerFactory.create(TubelineAssemblerFactory.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1642)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I also tried adding the dependencies in the sources of Tomcat inside Netbeans, still no good. 
Does anyone have any recommendation about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If on a Mac, run your tomcat folder through the Batchmod app to clear file permission related metadata.

---

Ignore Netbeans for now. Just you, a fresh Tomcat folder, a command line console (`Terminal` app if on a Mac), and a mug of coffee.

Download and install a fresh Tomcat. See if it runs. Use a browser pointing to Tomcat using the default port:

`http://localhost:8080/`

Stop Tomcat. Install one of your desired jars. Run Tomcat. Verify with a browser. Hit Reload feature on your browser to make sure you are not looking at a cached page.

Lather. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry, the title of the question was misleading. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this question's answer:
[tomcat 7.0.40 deployment severe wsservlet 11 Deployment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808097/tomcat-7-0-40-deployment-severe-wsservlet-11-deployment-error?rq=1)

I downloaded the metro jars, and just add them to the project's libs. Than it worked!